# Python: How to avoid exec()?

Tags: python, exec

I have written the following function:

```
def get_id(arg_a: int, arg_b: int, arg_c: int, arg_d: int) -> str:
    '''Construct some example id for stackoverflow.'''
    if isinstance(arg_a, float):
        arg_a = int(arg_a)
    if isinstance(arg_b, float):
        arg_b = int(arg_b)
    if isinstance(arg_c, float):
        arg_c = int(arg_c)
    if isinstance(arg_d, float):
        arg_d = int(arg_d)
    return f'{arg_a}|{arg_b}|{arg_c}|{arg_d}'
```

When I started to refactor my program, I found this function to be written not in as much pythonic way as I would like, so I started to think, how to rewrite it. I found out, I could use `exec()` in combination with `get_id.__code__.co_varnames`, which will provide a tuple with function arguments to iterate over:

```
def get_id(arg_a: int, arg_b: int, arg_c: int, arg_d: int) -> str:
    '''Construct some example id for stackoverflow.'''
    for arg in get_id.__code__.co_varnames:
        exec(f'{arg} = int({arg}) if isinstance({arg}, float) else {arg}')
    return f'{arg_a}|{arg_b}|{arg_c}|{arg_d}'
```

But after that, I found out that `exec()` function is not suggested to be used in production programs from many reasons, which I understand. But I do not know, what to use instead of `exec()`. Please, could you help me, how to write my function in more general way and without `exec()` function?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see there are three answers already, but I still think that it is worth asking why you thought that exec was needed here in the first place. If you literally just remove it, and the f string inside it, you can just RUN what you are currently EXECing. Why did you think you needed to use exec? What were you stuck on that required that?

Comment: @Neil Because OP is doing *variable variables*…

Comment: oh i see. hmm okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight forward way is this:

```
def get_id(*args: int) -> str:
    return '|'.join(map(str, map(int, args)))
```

Nothing happens if you put an `int` through `int()`, so you can apply it to floats and ints alike.

If you want to list your parameters explicitly one by one:

```
def get_id(arg_a: int, arg_b: int, arg_c: int, arg_d: int) -> str:
    return '|'.join(map(str, map(int, (arg_a, arg_b, arg_c, arg_d))))
```